# iOS Swift - Loading custom table cells

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

What is the most efficient way for showing multiple tables in a single UIViewController? Only one is visible at any given time and the user manipulates a segmentedControl to switch what is currently visible. I was able to accomplish it using 3 tableViews, but it seems messy. Here is my relevant code:

```
// Main UIViewController for handling 3 tableViews
class AnimalViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    let dogs = ["English Bulldog", "Labrador Retriever"]
    let cats = ["Persian", "Siamese"]
    let rabbits = ["Lionhead", "Rex"]

    @IBOutlet weak var segmentedControl: UISegmentedControl!
    @IBOutlet weak var dogsTableView: UITableView!
    @IBOutlet weak var catsTableView: UITableView!
    @IBOutlet weak var rabbitsTableView: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        self.dogsTableView.hidden = false
        self.catsTableView.hidden = true
        self.rabbitsTableView.hidden = true
    }

    @IBAction func indexChanged(sender: UISegmentedControl) {
        switch sender.selectedSegmentIndex {
        case 0:
            self.dogsTableView.hidden = false
            self.catsTableView.hidden = true
            self.rabbitsTableView.hidden = true
        case 1:
            self.dogsTableView.hidden = true
            self.catsTableView.hidden = false
            self.rabbitsTableView.hidden = true
        case 2:
            self.dogsTableView.hidden = true
            self.catsTableView.hidden = true
            self.rabbitsTableView.hidden = false
        default:
            break;
        }
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        var count: Int = 0

        if (tableView == self.dogsTableView) {
            println("dogs count")
            count = self.dogs.count
        }
        else if (tableView == self.catsTableView) {
            println("cats count")
            count = self.cats.count
        }
        else if (tableView == self.rabbitsTableView) {
            println("rabbits count")
            count = self.rabbits.count
        }

        return count
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        var cell: UITableViewCell!

        if (tableView == self.dogsTableView) {
            println("dogs count")

            var cell = self.dogsTableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as? DogTableViewCell

            if (cell == nil) {
                let nib = NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("DogTableViewCell", owner: DogTableViewCell.self, options: nil) as NSArray
                cell = nib.objectAtIndex(0) as? DogTableViewCell
            } 

            cell?.loadDog(breed: self.dogs[indexPath.row])

            return cell!
        }
        else if (tableView == self.catsTableView) {
            println("cats count")

            var cell = self.catsTableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as? CatTableViewCell

            if (cell == nil) {
                let nib = NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("CatTableViewCell", owner: CatTableViewCell.self, options: nil) as NSArray
                cell = nib.objectAtIndex(0) as? CatTableViewCell
            }

            cell?.loadCat(breed: self.cats[indexPath.row])

            return cell!
        }
        else if (tableView == self.rabbitsTableView) {
            println("rabbits count")

            var cell = self.rabbitsTableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as? RabbitTableViewCell

            if (cell == nil) {
                let nib = NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("RabbitTableViewCell", owner: RabbitTableViewCell.self, options: nil) as NSArray
                cell = nib.objectAtIndex(0) as? RabbitTableViewCell
            }

            cell?.loadRabbit(breed: self.rabbits[indexPath.row])

            return cell!
        }
        else {
            return cell!
        }
    }
}

// Dog, Cat, and Rabbit Table View Cell files (essentially the same, see Dog is shown below)
class DogTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var titleLabel: UILabel!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String!) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
    }

    func loadDog(#breed: String) {
        self.titleLabel.text = breed
    }

}
```

Comment: or maybe use a tab view controller without a tab bar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably more efficient, but you just discard the idea of having 3 table views. How about just make 1 table view and change the data source, making a switch for the selected segment. For example in your number of sections and number of rows for sections and cellForRowAtIndexPath methods:

```
switch segmentControl.selectedIndex {
case 0:
    // data source for index 0
case 1: 
    // data source for index 1
case 2: 
    // data source for index 2
default:
    break
}
```

And when the segment control changes reload the data source

Comment: So if I have custom cells for each animal, I could just load the custom cell dynamically into the one table?

Comment: In the cellForRowAtIndexPath just dequeue a different reusable cell in each case in a similar way to how your code already is in that method

Comment: Ok cool. I'm playing with it now, but I'm just a little confused on how to change the data source.

Comment: You don't physically change the data source. With the switch statements inside the data source methods you check the index of the segment control and when the segment value is changed you reload the table view

Comment: Nice! So essentially I added a variable to track the indexValue and instead of conditionally checking which tableView was visible, I'm just checking what the indexValue is. Thanks!

Comment: Pretty much, but you don't even need to create a variable to track the indexValue because you always have access to segmentedControl.selectedIndex

Comment: Gotcha! I was still trying to use my indexChanged function, but if I would have just read your question more closely I would have realized you wanted me to put that switch statement directly in my tableView methods!

Answer (score 0):

If possible just split the animals in UITableView sections by using the NSFetchedResultsController.

Look at this question: [Creating sections with NSFetchedResultsController, on the fly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14171474/creating-sections-with-nsfetchedresultscontroller-on-the-fly)

Comment: Thanks but that's not what I'm looking for. I would like to use 3 different table views and have them correspond to the segmentedControl.