# Grouping core data with NSFetchedResultsController in swift

Tags: swift, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I'm displaying core data using NSFetchedResultsController. Below is my CoreData class

```
class Item: NSManagedObject {
    @NSManaged var category: String
    @NSManaged var dateAdded: NSDate
    @NSManaged var image: String
    @NSManaged var name: String
    @NSManaged var subCategory: String
}
```

I want to display all items in groups. Items will be grouped based on the months of the dateAdded. That is, section header will display month and row will display the items added in that month.

Below is my code for NSFetchedResultsController

```
var fetchedResultsController: NSFetchedResultsController = {
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Item")

    let sort = NSSortDescriptor(key: "dateAdded", ascending: false)
    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sort]

    fetchRequest.fetchBatchSize = 20

    let result = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest, managedObjectContext: self.appDelegate.childManagedObjectContext!, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)
    result.delegate = self

    return result
}()
```

How can I achieve this. Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [Creating sections with NSFetchedResultsController, on the fly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14171474/creating-sections-with-nsfetchedresultscontroller-on-the-fly)

Comment: Apple provides sample code, "Custom Section Titles with NSFetchedResultsController" which should give you a starting point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easiest way is to add an attribute `dateAddedMonth` to store your `NSDate` only with the month. You can then set `sectionNameKeyPath` to `"dateAddedMonth"`.

Answer (score 9):

I solved it as

```
class Item: NSManagedObject {
    @NSManaged var category: String
    @NSManaged var dateAdded: NSDate
    @NSManaged var image: String
    @NSManaged var name: String
    @NSManaged var subCategory: String

    var groupByMonth: String{
    get{
        let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MMM yyyy"
        return dateFormatter.stringFromDate(self.dateAdded)
    }
}

var fetchedResultsController: NSFetchedResultsController = {
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Item")

    let sort = NSSortDescriptor(key: "dateAdded", ascending: false)
    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sort]

    fetchRequest.fetchBatchSize = 20

    let result = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest, managedObjectContext: self.appDelegate.childManagedObjectContext!, sectionNameKeyPath: groupByMonth, cacheName: nil)
    result.delegate = self

    return result
}()
```

Comment: This is a much cleaner solution to have a computed property

Comment: For newer versions of swift, Adding `@objc` at the beginning of `groupByMonth` is necessary.

Comment: Could you please guide me how to get distinct record using ID with fetchResult controller. I tried.  


var groupById: String {
        get {
            return self.id ?? ""
        }
    }